# Navigation through ID by click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working in website,I have 2 page index.html and product.html,In product.html
i have 2 div element with different ID,Now when i click the anchor tag  in index.html which navigate to product.html but it should navigate to particular ID which holding different content in product.html need help

```
In index.html page i have anchor tag  
<a href=products.html>Building</a>
<a href=products.html>Infrastructure</a>
```

In product.html page i got 2 div

```
 <div id=#Building>
<div class="container">
</div>
<div>

<div id=#Infrastructure>
<div class="container">
</div>
<div>
```

when i click the anchor tag i should navigate to particular ID like if i click Infrastructure anchor tag it should directly navigate to product.html infrastructure div

Comment: What did you tried so far ? Dump some code to get help on SO

Comment: please add some code

Comment: @kitty
In that href you can also mention the div id you want.
=> `href="product.html#myDiv"`

Comment: its not working for me it redirecting to the page,not to particular ID of the div

Answer (score 0):

just add that id to your href.
like product.html#divid

index.html

```
<html>
<body>
<a href='products.html#Building'>Building</a>
<a href='products.html#Infrastructure'>Infrastructure</a>
</body>
</html>

products.html

<div id='Building'>
<div class="container">
 building<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
<div>

<div id='Infrastructure'>
<div class="container">
Infrastructure
</div>
<div>
```

create inedx.html and products.html files and paste above code.
it working as expected.

Comment: its not working for me it redirecting to the page,not to particular ID of the div

Comment: you gave ids wrong way that why its not working.correct them then it ill work.

Comment: i tried it,its not working for me,index.html and product.html both are different page